# uibutton with png cause uiscrollview to lag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, lag

I have an UIScrollView with 15 UIButton (create with a storyboard)

When I zoom or Scroll it's laggy.

the trace for a scroll is :

`Running Time   Self        Symbol Name
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0     Main Thread  0x61091
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0      start
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0       main
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0        top_level_code
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0         UIApplicationMain
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0          GSEventRun
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0           GSEventRunModal
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0            CFRunLoopRunInMode
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0             CFRunLoopRunSpecific
434.0ms  100.0% 0,0              __CFRunLoopRun
417.0ms   96.0% 0,0               __CFRunLoopDoObservers
417.0ms   96.0% 0,0                __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
415.0ms   95.6% 0,0                 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
413.0ms   95.1% 0,0                  CA::Transaction::commit()
413.0ms   95.1% 0,0                   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                    CA::Layer::prepare_commit(CA::Transaction*)
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                     CA:: ::prepare_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                      CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double)
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                       CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int)
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                        CGImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetWithOptions
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                         ImageProviderCopyImageBlockSetCallback
406.0ms   93.5% 0,0                          copyImageBlockSetPNG
331.0ms   76.2% 0,0                           _cg_png_read_row
207.0ms   47.6% 1,0                            png_read_IDAT_data
203.0ms   46.7% 12,0                                inflate
177.0ms   40.7% 0,0                              <Unknown Address>
168.0ms   38.7% 166,0                                 0x257f24e
2.0ms    0.4%   0,0                                i386_astintr
2.0ms    0.4%   2,0                                 ast_taken
3.0ms    0.6%   3,0                               0x257f0cb
2.0ms    0.4%   2,0                               0x257ef8b
2.0ms    0.4%   2,0                               0x257efcb
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                               0x257f1f0
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                               0x257effb
10.0ms    2.3%  0,0                              adler32
3.0ms    0.6%   0,0                              0x257c67c
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                              0x257eee0
2.0ms    0.4%   0,0                             png_crc_read
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                             <Unknown Address>
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                              0x257eee0
68.0ms   15.6%  0,0                            png_read_filter_row
47.0ms   10.8%  7,0                            png_do_read_transformations
7.0ms    1.6%   1,0                            png_combine_row
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                            png_read_finish_IDAT
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                            _platform_memmove$VARIANT$sse42
69.0ms   15.8%  18,0                              _platform_memmove$VARIANT$sse42
50.0ms   11.5%  10,0                               user_trap
37.0ms    8.5%  3,0                             vm_fault_internal
2.0ms    0.4%   2,0                             kernel_debug
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                             <Unknown Address>
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                            thread_exception_return
2.0ms    0.4%   0,0                           _cg_png_read_info
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                           ImageIO_make_read_only
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                           _cg_png_destroy_read_struct
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                           CGImageRead_mapData
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                           <Unknown Address>
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                            png_read_IDAT_data
7.0ms    1.6%   0,0                    CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
1.0ms    0.2%   1,0                  objc_autoreleasePoolPush
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0                  (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
2.0ms    0.4%   0,0                 _afterCACommitHandler
16.0ms    3.6%  0,0               __CFRunLoopDoSources0
1.0ms    0.2%   0,0               __CFRunLoopDoTimer`

Is there any way to avoid this lag? why the uiimage are render each time? can't it be done in background?

PS : all the button are visible in the view.

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hey. Have you found a solution for this issue? I have `UICollectionViewCells` with `UIImage` and it's lagging on scroll. after profiling it, I have noticed it was taking a lot of time with the `png_read_IDAT_data` as you've described. I have no idea how to improve this and I'd like to know what was your approach